# Is the Schrödinger Equation unsolvable even if we hurl random functions at it until one sticks?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

So we have the Time Independent Schrödinger Equation, shown in Equation \eqref{schrodinger-equation}.

$$
\tag{1}
\label{schrodinger-equation}
\hat H\psi(\vec x)=E\psi(\vec x)
$$

The solutions to that equation are the stationary states of the system described by the Hamiltonian operator $\hat H$. Rearranging Equation \eqref{schrodinger-equation} we get Equation \eqref{alternative-schrodinger-equation}, shown below:

$$
\tag{2}
\label{alternative-schrodinger-equation}
\frac{\hat H \psi}{\psi} = E
$$

Correct me if I am wrong but Equation \eqref{alternative-schrodinger-equation} is saying that if we take a function $f$, which respects the boundary conditions, and apply $\hat H$ to it, then it turns into a new function $g$. If $\frac{g}{f}$ equals $E$ in all of coordinate space (a constant function) then $f$ is a stationary state of $\hat H$ with energy $E$.

I am aware that the Schrödinger Equation cannot be solved using current analytical methods. But suppose we have:

- Infinite time
- A collaborator named **Sue**, who generates random $f(\vec x)$ functions that respect the boundary conditions for the equation. Sue's job is to prevent useless functions (like constant functions) from seeping in such that any $f$ she generates that solves the equation does so because it is a valid solution.
- Another colaborator called **Phil**, who can do all the algebraic work of plugging $f$ on Equation $\eqref{alternative-schrodinger-equation}$ and figuring out whether the expression for ${\hat H f}/f$ has no coordinate symbols (meaning it is a constant function in coordinate space, and thus a solution).

**If we let Sue throw functions at Phil for long enough, will he eventually find a function $\psi$ that is a solution to the Time Independent Schrodinger Equation?**

This is a concrete example and food for thought but the underlying question is
whether the equation has been proven entirely unsolvable or is it just that it lacks some properties required to be solved by the current available methods.

Comment: 1) it is not true that the Schrodinger eq is unsolvable. 2) what you propose is very close to the variational method of approximation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unsolvable" in the context here typically doesn't refer to the sense of, say, the halting problem, but usually that a differential equation doesn't have a solution in terms of elementary functions (or elementary functions with certain special functions adjoined, etc.) The idea can be made more precise with differential Galois theory, though it may be a bit of a niche field.

For the specific idea you propose, it's not trivial to determine whether a function is constant or vanishes everywhere. Having no variables explicitly appear in an expression is clearly sufficient, but it's not necessary; consider something like $\sin x + \sin (-x)$. For a less trivial example, see Richardson's theorem. The other issue is that the space of real functions (or functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with some degree of differentiability) is not countable, so there's no way of methodically cycling through them. Compare the situation to that of trying to find the zero a function $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by repeatedly drawing a point $x\in [0, 1]$ uniformly at random, computing $f(x)$, and checking whether it's $0$ (even assuming infinite precision).

Comment: Even if the space of real functions is not countable, we are not trying to systematically go over every function, we are just randomly generating functions, and supposing that our method is unable to detect the examples such as sin(x)-sin(-x) as valid (it can only see the constant functions), could we, in principle, find solutions even to the multi-electron equation?

Comment: Assuming you have a countable number of attempts and a "reasonable" probability distribution on the space of sufficiently smooth functions, the probability that you draw the solution is $0$.